# Chrome remote debug Samsung Galaxy s4

Tags: android, debugging, google-chrome

I tried to use the remote debugging tool of Google Chrome for my Samsung Galaxy S4 (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging?hl=nl). But my Chrome does not found my device after i used about:inspect. The list stays empty.

I already install the newest driver on my computer and both devices running Chrome version 32. On my phone the USB debugging checkbox is checked.

Does someone know what i can do to view my phone trough Chrome debugging?

Comment: Do you see your device attached to the machine as a Media device?  If not then there is a chance the cable you are using is a power only cable and not a data cable.

Comment: Same issue with a Galaxy Tab 2 10.1, everything up-to-date and connected as a media device. I'll post an answer as soon as I figure this one out.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Do you have ADT (Android Development Toolkit) installed? If so, you may have to restart the ADB server. Follow these steps: (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22028058/563970)).

1. Open a command prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, "`cmd.exe`", <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. Go to the `platform-tools` directory of your locally installed ADT. In my case:

   ```
   cd /d D:\apps\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools
   ```
3. Restart the ADT server by running the following commands:

   ```
   adb.exe kill-server
   adb.exe start-server
   ```
4. Now observe that your tablet will ask for remote debugging permission (by checking a fingerprint) upon connection.
5. The device should now be found if you open `chrome://inspect`.

Comment: restarting server helped also in Samsung Galaxy Core so I suppose it will help on any device. It's hard to find that solution so many thanks for that!

Comment: in my case path was: C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
device: SM-T520

Answer (score 16):

**workaround if you don't have ADT (Android Development Toolkit) installed:**

Managed to detect android based Samsung Galaxy phone after downloading [andorid SDK platform-tools.zip](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=9390355257214632011) and running the following command: "adb devices".
It started some deamon, found attached device, and I was also able to see it in chrome canary inspect tab.

previously I also installed ["Universal ADB driver"](https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver) but not sure if this was required

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy. Nothing to install too - just extract the folder, go to folder in command prompt and run "adb devices". The connection prompt popped up straight away on my S5 Mini and I was up and running.

Comment: This is working. You rock! (No need to Unversal ADB driver)

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled over this exact problem. The solution above work's like a charm for me.
But I'm lazy as hell, so I created a **.bat** file:

```
@ECHO OFF 
cmd.exe /K "cd C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools && C: & adb.exe kill-server & adb.exe start-server"
```

The directory depends on your installation of your ADT.

Save as killstart_adb.bat and run this.
Works for me.