# Why chrome remote debugging is not working on my Samsung Galaxy S10?

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, samsung-galaxy

I've checked this question [Chrome remote debug Samsung Galaxy s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546468/chrome-remote-debug-samsung-galaxy-s4)
It is pretty old and I cannot believe that this issue is still not fixed in 2019.
I did everything as in this video: [Setting Up Google Chrome Remote Debugging On Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug6TTlSmEvY) and this tutorial [Get Started with Remote Debugging Android Devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) but Chrome on my Windows machine does not detect my device - Samsung Galaxy S10. Any idea how to solve this in 2019?
[image: Windows 1]
[image: Windows 2]
[image: Android 1]
[image: Android 2]

Comment: Are you running ADB-over-wifi on Android or did you connect it to the computer via data cable and did you run `adb connect`?  P.S. I didn't watch/read all the resources you've linked.

Comment: Installing ADB and running "adb devices" solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Koralek M. for this answer [Chrome DevTools Devices does not detect device when plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57524521/5841485). Installing ADB and running "adb devices" solved the problem!